# Ref "is not a type" - storing a type in a struct

Tags: go

I have a file like so:

```
package foo
type Handler struct {}
```

and then in another file, I have:

```
import (
   "handlers/foo"
   "handlers/bar"
   "handlers/baz"
)

type AllHandlers struct {
    Foo foo.Handler
    Bar bar.Handler
    Baz baz.Handler
}
```

then in another file I have:

```
all := routes.AllHandlers{}
foo := all.Foo{}
bar := all.Bar{}
baz := all.Baz{}
```

but it gives me this error:

> Foo is not a type

I am probably doing some egregiously wrong. What I want to do is store all handlers in the AllHandlers struct, but not sure how to do that.

I believe the question can be simplified in this way:

```
func (h HuruInjection) GetInjections() struct{} {
    return struct {
        Foo foo.Handler
        Bar  bar.Handler
        Baz baz.Handler
    }
}
```

the above won't compile, essentially because you are returning a type instead of a value, as far as I can tell - for example, a Class instead of an instance of that Class. How can I get this to compile?

See this example: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/894438aee1d16aa9b2cb12ba25df274e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182623/discussion-between-weavr-and-alexander-mills).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming for, so I can't tell you how to fix it. But it's pretty obvious that `all.Foo` is not a type, from what you've pasted. The only type you've mentioned exported by the `all` package is `AllHandlers`. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Your last paragraph only confuses me more. It's very confusing to talk about classes in Go, since Go doesn't have classes.

Comment: Solved it, in order to export a type from file x, where the type is originally declared in file y, I used the method in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the trick is to use the right syntax. Instead of doing this:

```
import (
   "handlers/foo"
   "handlers/bar"
   "handlers/baz"
)

type AllHandlers struct {
    Foo foo.Handler
    Bar bar.Handler
    Baz baz.Handler
}
```

I did this:

```
import (
   "handlers/foo"
   "handlers/bar"
   "handlers/baz"
)


type Foo = foo.Handler
type Bar = bar.Handler
type Baz = baz.Handler
```

then I could import this, and use Foo, Bar, Baz as types. So I don't think you can group types in a struct, but you can import/export types by using the above syntax.